# render anomaly chart shows me strange values for x

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm using a render anomaly chart but instead of having the respective variable value and the date, I got the variable value a a extract big number.

I would like to know if I'm writing the wrong instruction or if I'm missing something.

I run the example that is part of the documentation and it seems that the problem is there as well.

Thanks.

```
C26503T
| make-series Variable=avg(Value) default=average on todatetime(Timestamp) from (_startTime-304m) to (_endTime-304m) step dtfinal
| extend fill_forward=series_fill_linear(Variable,real(null),true)
| extend (anomalies,score, baseline) = series_decompose_anomalies(fill_forward,Treshold, -1, 'linefit')
| project-away score
| render anomalychart  with(anomalycolumns=anomalies, fill_forward,title="Compressor anomalies", ysplit=panels)
```

Comment: Hi there,Any news?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using KE (the desktop app) or KWE? For KE, you pass some wrong paramters to the render line:

```
| render anomalychart  with(anomalycolumns=anomalies, fill_forward,title="Compressor anomalies", ysplit=panels)
```

Should be:

```
| render anomalychart  with(anomalycolumns=anomalies, ycolumns= fill_forward,title="Compressor anomalies")
```

Also, please specify the example in the doc that didn't work for you, whether you use KE or KWE, best if you add your query and a screenshot of the chart